# Delete the first two row's of every sheet of every file within a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will when executed will delete the first two rows of every sheets, of every folder within a spreadsheet.

The problem is I have about 50 spreadsheets all with about 15 sheets so do them individually will take a quite a while, but I have no idea where to start with the code.

The long game is that these sheets will all be merged by sheets name i.e sheet CB of spreadsheet 1 will be merged with sheet CB of spreadsheet 2/3/4 and so on, not sure if this is possible yet, but I need to get the row headers as the first line before I begin to look at that task.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction with my initial problem.

This is the code I have so far;

```
function myFunction() {

/* Retrieve the desired folder */
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1CFkTW0xR50psbVzu35_EsW-ytSeTqoKz");

/* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

/* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

/* Open the spreadsheet */
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

/* Get all its sheets */
for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

  /* Get Rows to delete */
  var Rnage = spreadSheet.deleteRow(2)

   }
 }      
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1CFkTW0xR50psbVzu35_EsW-ytSeTqoKz");
  var spreadSheets= myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
    var spreadsheet = spreadSheets.next();
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.getId());
    var shts=ss.getSheets();
    for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
      shts[i].deleteRows(1, 2);
    }
  }      
}
```